# json.net doesn't ignore circular references when set to ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, serialization, json.net

This project I'm working with used to have a new DbContext created per each repository method (which meant that every request had an arbitrary number of dbcontexts created) on each web request.

I've solved that to only have one context per request but some of the serialization goes haywire and gets an out of memory exception. Looking at the serialized data, Json.Net is completely ignoring the `ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore` enum value for circular reference handling. Note that when I set it to `ReferenceLoopHandling.Error`, I will get an exception immediately on self-referencing object.

This happens with both Proxies and Lazy loading enabled and disabled.

Full list of settings used for JsonSerializer:

`DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local,
Formatting = Formatting.None,
ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include`

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the problem?  This will make it much easier for someone to help you.

Answer (score 5):

Try setting [`SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveReferencesHandlingObject.htm) to `PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects`, so that references to existing objects are performed using references instead of re-serializing the object.

Comment: I know this is old but this is affecting me now too.  This suggestion will stop the error from occurring but will then cause you to have to read your JSON in a completely different way.  Why doesn't the object just do what it says its gonna do?